Ramification for a Galois extension of number fields
Let $f\in {\mathbb Z}[x]$ be a polynomial with discriminant $d\in {\mathbb Z}$.
Let $L/{\mathbb Q}$ be the Galois extension obtained by adjoining to ${\mathbb Q}$ all roots of $f$.

Claim. For all primes $p$ not dividing $2d$, the extension $L/{\mathbb Q}$ is unramified at $p$.


Question. Is the claim true, and if yes, where can I find a proof of this claim?


You can find a proof in these lecture notes:
https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/ant.pdf
See theorem 4.14, and also theorem 4.10 if you need the relation between the discriminants of $f$ and $L$.

Thank you, this is what I was looking for!
